# How to Flatten & Secure PDF Files?

Tags: security, layers

From my readings of past and somewhat similar threads, it sounds like there is no LaTeX code for creating a PDF that is both "flattened" and "secured". Therefore, I need to compile the PDF then use other software, such as Adobe Acrobat Pro, to secure them.

Is that correct?

My goal is to create salable PDFs which contain roadblocks to copying, editing, stealing, etc. portions of that PDF.

Comment: `pdftk` (https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can both flatten and secure.

Comment: qpdf (http://qpdf.sf.net) can also do this. I have almost finished writing an arara rule to do just that with it. you can have a look and test it by downloading it at (https://gist.github.com/ArTourter/a0f464b9018bd74fe1a5fce2800784ef). it still needs a bit a polishing and a documentation, but it is fully functional.

Comment: @Thérèse -- `pdftk` looks pretty good, thank you! My only concern is that it says it's compatible with Windows XP, Vista *barf*, 7, and 8. It does not mention 10. Is this software updated often enough in terms of safety and compatibility?

Comment: @ ArTourter -- What is an "arara" rule? And what would I do with this code? Would I just paste it into a .tex file and...

Comment: there were talks (or at least requests) on the texlive mailing list a few years back to have qpdf part of texlive but it doesn't seem to have materialised. I used to used pdftk a lot for this but it is basically abandonware now unfortunately. qpdf seems very much alive.

Comment: arara is a  TeX automation tool, like latexmk. (https://github.com/cereda/arara). the file is a yaml file which tells arara what to do. if you are not familiar with arara, it my not be that much use though.

Comment: I use `pdftk` on GNU/Linux.  Sorry, I don’t know anything about Windows. For encryption, I prefer `qpdf`, which ArTourter recommended; I wasn’t aware that it could handle flattening also.

Comment: What is the advantage of `qpdf` over `pdftk`?

Comment: It may just be a matter of which versions of the two programs are available in my Linux distribution, but `qpdf` has stronger encryption.

Comment: Regarding the flattening part, I am not sure qpdf does the same as pdftk. qpdf has a `--linearize` option which when used, the document is recognised by Adobe Reader as having "Fast Web View" and pdfinfo describes it as "optimized". Is that the same as flattened?

Comment: Flattening effectively removes some of the interactive feature of a pdf so embedded 3D, flash, form fields, comments and other annotation are usually simplified to crude graphics/icons. I helps to make the file less useful. You cannot make a pdf secure unless you don't publish it and keep it in a safe.

Comment: It takes you hours to find a method to put up roadblocks of concrete barbed-wire and even pay someone to hold up a stop sign but it only takes seconds for a pirate to walk through on their way to websites. The best snake oil (I have seen their system defeated) is the same one that tells you how insecure other pdfs really are https://www.locklizard.com/pdf_security_drm/